# How to split strings based on special character (multiple times)

Tags: excel, vba, string

I'm trying to split a string based on ampersand (&), remove all the ampersands and separate each part to columns.

The number of strings differ every time.

Sample text:

[image]

My output:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

```
For i = 2 To 7
    fullname = Cells(i, 1).Value
    commaposition = InStr(fullname, "&")

    Cells(i, 2).Value = Left(fullname, commaposition - 2)

    For x = 2 To 7
        fullname = Cells(i, 1).Value
        commaposition = InStr(fullname, "&")

        Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid(fullname, commaposition + 2)
        Cells(x, 3).Value = Mid(fullname, commaposition + 2)

        For y = 2 To 7
            fullname = Cells(i, 1).Value
            commaposition = InStr(fullname, "&")

            Cells(i, 4).Value = Mid(fullname, commaposition + 2)
            Cells(x, 4).Value = Mid(fullname, commaposition + 2)

        Next y
    Next x
Next i
```

Comment: Have you tried [Split](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-instr/#The_Split_Function)?

Comment: Or Text to Columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option (other then @Storax's method) would be to use Regular Expressions which could account for more then just an ampersand.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FindNames()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim j As Long
    Dim c, Match

    ' Update for your range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    End With

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\w+"

        For Each c In rng
            j = 0
            If .test(c.Value2) Then
                For Each Match In .Execute(c.Value2)
                    j = j + 1
                    c.Offset(0, j).Value2 = Match
                Next Match
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I never thought of using regexp for it. This really worked. Thanks so much. But is it possible for it to not include spaces? @Tom

Comment: @cap36 The pattern should already ignore the spaces but just to be on the safe side you could always `Trim` the `Match`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that

```
Sub SplitAmper()

Const AP = "&"
Dim v As Variant
Dim rg As Range

    Set rg = Range("A2:A7") ' Adjust to your needs

    Dim sngCell As Range
    For Each sngCell In rg
        v = Split(sngCell.Value, AP)
        Cells(sngCell.Row, 1).Resize(, UBound(v) + 1) = v
    Next

End Sub
```

**Update**: Another solution mentioned in the comments from SJR would be *Text to Columns*

```
Sub AnotherAmper()

Const AP = "&"
Dim rg As Range

Set rg = Range("A1:A7")    ' Adjust to your needs


    rg.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                     Other:=True, OtherChar:=AP

End Sub
```

Comment: how about `sngCell.Resize(, UBound(v) + 1) = v`

Comment: I'm getting Application-defined or object-defined error for this one.

Comment: Yes, of course, you get that if the input cell is empty.